# Referencing a resource dictionary from another file in the project

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a resource dictionary with one data template inside.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2"
        xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/">

    <DataTemplate x:Key="CircuitBreakerClose">
        <Grid>
            <Path Stroke="Green" Fill="Transparent" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Fill">
                <Path.Data>
                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,50,50"></RectangleGeometry>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

I am trying to access this from this other file like so.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <converters:UniqueIdImageSourceConverter x:Key="uniqueIdImageSourceConverter" />
        
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="ResourceDictionary">
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="C:/Cfg/Screens/Themes/Resources/DynamicControlCircuitBreaker.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
        
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CircuitBreakerClose"/>

</UserControl.Resources>

    <DataTemplate>
        <Button>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
               
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                    <ContentControl.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                            
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CircuitBreakerClose}"/>
          
                            </Style>
                        </ContentControl.Style>
                    </ContentControl>
                
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I am new to wpf and I am having trouble getting this to display. I believe I have referenced it incorrectly. Could someone please explain how to reference to the resource in the resource dictionary.

Comment: You have not shown the namespaces in your project and the structure of its folders, so it is impossible to accurately answer.
The following is exactly possible: the full path you specified is suitable for external files, and your dictionary is a resource embedded in the assembly.
Specifying such a complete path will lead to problems when porting the finished application.

Comment: Try this.
Place the keyboard cursor inside the `ResourceDictionary Source = ...` line.
Open the Property Browser.
Find the Source property in it.
There should be a ComboBox.
Having opened it, you should see all the valid resources of your project.
Select your dictionary and Studio will insert the correct Uri.

Comment: @bigboy: Remove `<DataTemplate x:Key="CircuitBreakerClose"/>` from `<UserControl.Resources>`?